# finding the frequency of each row (2)

Tags: matlab

Per my previous question, I have several mx2 matrices with rows from (0,1), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1), (1,1), (-1,1), (1,-1),(-1,-1) and I would like to find the frequency of each of above coordinates, I used unique and hisc to give me the frequency of each row. Now, since I would like to compare different matrices, I would like for each matrix have a corresponding output of 8 rows, where each row indicates the number of times that each of above coordinates appear. In particular, if e.g (0,1) is not among the rows of my matrix, I would like to see zero frequency.

For instance, if A=[1 1; 0 1; 1 0; -1 1;-1 1;0 1;0 1]

I would like to see something like:

```
-1    -1   0
-1     0   0
-1     1   2
 0    -1   0
 0     1   3
 1    -1   0
 1     0   1
 1     1   1
```

Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: How do you determine which rows to add in the computation? For example, why do you consider row `-1 -1` and not `0 0`?

Comment: Those 8 coordinates which I mentioned actually indicate the direction of a player in a game, e.g. (-1,-1) is going backward. There is no (0,0) in this game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A =     [ 1  1
          0  1
          1  0
         -1  1
         -1  1
          0  1
          0  1 ];

rows = [ -1 -1
         -1  0
         -1  1
          0 -1
          0  1
          1 -1
          1  0
          1  1 ];

count = sum(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A.', permute(rows, [2 3 1])))));
```

Of course, if you need the result in the form shown in your question, just build the matrix `result = [rows count.']`.